# Get all events with specific key from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have topics in my system that store events for given entities. Now I would like to perform some analysis on the eventlog. Therefore I need to query all events belonging to some entity within a certain time period. Is there a possibility to aggregate all events of a certain key within a TimeWindow using Kafka Streams?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want the `groupByKey` method of the DSL

Comment: Okay, but how would it be possible to query the datapoints with a certain key?

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting. Have you researched the Interactive Queries feature or KSQL?

Comment: Yes I know interactive queries, but the problem is that I was only able to get the "latest" value for some key. But how to query for the previous values for that key?

Comment: You would store both values in the message when you group the key, not only the "other" value that's being merged in

Comment: I see. So I would use e.g. aggregate to add the oldValue to the message?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how you want to setup your system, what kind of analysis you want to do and what you exactly mean by "querying"

For a one-time analysis, you might just want to do a `stream.transform(...).to()` and filter on key and timestamp (`context.timestamp()` is your friend) in your `Transformer` and write the result into a topic. Hence, you would run this program once for some key and time range. Maybe you could even do the required analysis before writing any result, you you use `WindowStore` (with duplication enabled) to buffer all data in the store).

If you want to write a program that *prepares* **all* data for analysis, you would use a `groupBy()` (or `grouByKey()`). Using `windowedBy()` with `TimeWindows` only works of you know the time ranges you want to group the data upfront (eg, hourly, or daily, or similar). For the aggregation itself, you could return a `List<Value>` object and accumulate the corresponding records per key and window. This way, you can use IQ to get all records for a specif key and window with a single lookup.